# How to drag/add my custom portlet to liferay page with admin Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I implemented a custom portlet with Lr 7.3.5 and the deployment was done successfully I want to drag this portlet to a page which I created with admin Liferay, the problem I didnt found the `+` button in the control menu to add the portlet by drag it inside the page

I used Liferay 7.3.5 latest version . Is someone has an idea maybe on how to show that btn or maybe i missed some thing .

Thanks

***screenshot:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Add button, you have to use the Edit button in the upper right corner, looks like a pencil (is also shown on you screenshot, next to where the plus sign used to be).
I downloaded the liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.5-ga6-20200930172312275.7z to test this, and once you click the Edit button, a new menu appears on the right hand side - here you have to click Widgets and you will find your custom portlet there (you can use the search, or maybe it is located under the Sample category)
I hope this answers your question